# Issue to scrape href using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am to scrape `href` but they give me `empty list`

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


class PushpaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pushpa'
    start_urls = ['http://smartcatalog.emo-milano.com/it/catalogo/elenco-alfabetico/400/A']

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath("//div[@class='exbox-name']/a/@href").extract():
            yield href
```

Comment: Try `yield {'href':href}` instead of `yield href` to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

did you enable logs to identify problems (LOG_LEVEL in settings.py) ? I think your parse function should return an item not a string, like that :

```
yield {'url': href}
```